Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components in Next.js
I’m working on a Next.js 14 project and encountering an issue where I receive the following error intermittently:
Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server.

The error appears when:

I press on an item for the first time after I run my localhost
I call revalidatePath("/bag") to update the item count in my navbar after adding an item to my shopping bag.

However, after refreshing the page, the error does not appear again.
async function getData(productId: string, lang: string) {
    const data = await (lang === "ru"
        ? prisma.ruProduct.findUnique({
              where: { ruProductId: productId },
              select: {
                  ruProductId: true,
              },
          })
        : prisma.euProduct.findUnique({
              where: { euProductId: productId },
              select: {
                  euProductId: true,
              },
          }));

    if (!data) {
        return notFound(); // Handles when product is not found
    }
    return data;
}

// Server Component for ProductPage
export default async function ProductPage({
    params,
}: {
    params: { id: string; lang: string };
}) {
    const { id, lang } = params;
    const data = await getData(id, lang);

    const productId =
        "ruProductId" in data ? data.ruProductId : data.euProductId;

    const addProductToShoppingBag = addItem.bind(null, productId);

    const currencySymbol = lang === "ru" ? "₽" : "€";

    return (
        <>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-6 items-start lg:gap-x-24 py-6">
                <ImageSlider images={data.images} />
                <div>
                    <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
                        {data.name}
                    </h1>
                    <p className="text-3xl mt-2 text-gray-900">
                        {currencySymbol}
                        {data.sellingPrice}
                    </p>
                    <p className="text-base text-gray-700 mt-6">
                        {data.description}
                    </p>

                    <form action={addProductToShoppingBag}>
                        <ShoppingBagButton lang={lang} />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="mt-16">
                <FeaturedProducts lang={lang} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}


I tried to add
"use client",

however I got this error:
Error: PrismaClient is unable to run in this browser environment, or has been bundled for the browser (running in `unknown`).
If this is unexpected, please open an issue: https://pris.ly/prisma-prisma-bug-report 

It also difficult to make the function not async or not default because i need both for getting data.
Why does this error occur the first time but not after refreshing the page?
How can I refactor my code to resolve this error?
